# java garbage collection issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've got a HashMap of Game objects. Each Game object contains a HashMap of Players and a list of Moves. When a game is over, I want to remove it from the map. Shall I empty players map and moves list before I remove the game object or will the GC take care of it?

Yep, that's a newbie question, sorry for that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring Players HashMap from Game object and when your game is over, and you are removing it from the map, players map will also be removed because it was referenced from game.

When the reference to game is lost then, all the objects which were referred from Game will also be lost if they are not reference from outside Game object

Well let us understand this using an example.

- We have a Door class and a Room class
- A Room will have a Door and it cannot exist without the room.

Let us see this code

```
public class Room {
Door door = new Door();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room room = new Room();
        room = null;
    }

}
```

Here, When we write `Room room = new Room()`, a `Room` object will be created, and because a `Door` is the instance variable for it, a `door` is also created. The `door` will be reference from room using `room.door`.
At this point of time, we can access `room` directly and its `door` can be accessed using room. So `door` object will have reference through `room`.

Now when we do `room = null`, we lose the reference to `Room` object. As the `Door` object is referenced only through `Room`, we have lost its only reference. As `room = null` we can't access `room.door`.

This is diagrammatically referred as follows

[image]

The first image shows the condition when `Room room = new Room();` gets executed.
It has reference to Door.

The second image denotes the condition after `room = null`.Please note that dotted line refers that the reference is lost. Now the reference for `Room` is lost and obviously for the `door` is also lost.

at this point of time...both objects will be eligible for garbage collection

Hope this answer helps a little bit :)

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to do anything.

As long as the entire object graph is not referenced by any *rooted* objects, the GC will collect the whole thing automatically.

A rooted object is an object the is guaranteed to not be collectible – an object referenced by a static field or by an active stack frame in any thread.

Comment: What do you mean by `rooted objects`? I know that GC will not touch anything that still have references somewhere, so do you mean that there is simply any other reference?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: If the thing referencing it is itself collectible, both will be collected.  See my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure "rooted" is a good description of the condition. Objects that are no longer accessible from any thread are eligible for garbage collection. If these objects reference other similarly inaccessible objects then the whole object graph is eligible. Such object graphs are called "Islands of Isolation"...

Comment: @Brabster: That's what I meant to say.

Comment: @Slaks feel free to take anything you want from my answer and use it in your own.

Comment: Oficially references to objects from Thread-Stacks are called "Root"-References. So there exists a root refernce to the HashMap with the Game objects. Via this root reference the players can be accessed

Comment: @AnarchoEnte if I get your point correctly, how can GC remove an object that is referenced (no matter how)?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz a referenced object can only be removed if the object referencing it is removed too.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz the GC can clean up any object which is not strongly "reachable" If you have A which references B but B references A this is not a problem if no other object references A or B, They both get cleaned up together.

Comment: @JanDvorak circular references are not a problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I never intended to imply they were. Only that any strongly connected components must be removed at the same time (unless the GC likes keeping unreachable dangling references around)

Comment: References from other objects are not important for the GC at first. Each object, which can not be accessed through a root reference (e.g. objects directly reachable out of Threads) can and will be removed during the next GC-cleanup. So the traditional memory leak can not occur (I don't say that in Java no memory leak can occur!).